# Does synchronized (vector<vector>) lock all of the Vectors or just the one storing them?

Tags: java, vector, synchronized

Say I have some vectors: v1, v2, v3

Say I also have a vector that holds these vList = {v1, v2, v3}

If I synchronized (vList), does this mean that v1, v2, and v3 are also locked or does it just lock vList?

Comment: That would be a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronized doesn't lock objects! It marks a critical section of code.

If you use it for a method (`synchronized void foo()`) only one Thread can access this method.

If you use it with an object (`synchronized(bar)`) only a thread owing the lock on this object can enter the critical zone.

This means synchronizing on 'bar' requires every thread that wants to enter this zone (or any other synced on 'bar') to request the lock. If they don't acquire it they are blocked until the Thread owning the lock releases it.

This means if all your vectors are only worked with in a block synchronized on one variable this is usually enough.

Syncing in multiple objects in a row is also no problem:

```
synchronized(bar){..} synchronized(foo){..}
```

Where it gets tricky is cascaded syncs as this may lead to [deadlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock):

```
synchronized(bar){
   synchronized(foo){..}
}
```

And last but not least:
You wont have to lock a Vector to make it threadsave as each method of vector is defined with `synchronized`(As seen [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Vector.java.html)). You only have to set up an additional lock if you want to edit multiple Vectors without interference from other Threads.

Comment: Your answer made it clear to me first. Thank you for the simple language!

Answer (score 3):

It's up to you to decide what the lock protects. If you decide it locks all three of them, then it locks all three of them. Just reflect that decision in all the code that accesses those objects.

The relationship between locks and objects is a code design concept that must be reflected in all the code that deals with the locked objects. To avoid race conditions and other bugs, programmers can use a lock to protect an object. We say lock "X" locks object "Y" if we intend that all accesses to object "Y" are performed while holding lock "X". Since only one thread can hold lock "X" at time, this rule ensures that only one thread at a time accesses object "Y". The lock does not know or care what object(s) it protects.

If all code that accesses "v1" holds the "vList" lock when it accesses it, then "vList" locks "v1". If there's some code that accesses "v1" without holding the "vList" lock, the "vList" does not lock "v1".

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean. Doesn't synchronized(foo) mean Java has some under the hood locks so that only a single thread can ever be touching foo? Why would this mean that I get to choose? Isn't the item I put in syncrhonized() the item that gets lock? (i did not downvote)

Comment: @MilanNovaković No, that's a misunderstanding! The under the hood locks ensures that only a single thread can ever **lock** `foo`. It's up to you to make sure no code touches `foo` without locking `foo`, if you want the `foo` lock to protect the `foo` object. Locks don't know or care what they protect. (Also, I don't know what you think it means for an item to "get" a lock, but it sounds like a confusion.)

Comment: Those last couple sentences edited to your response cleared it up for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Each `Vector<T>` is making only its own content thread-safe:

- `Vector<Vector<T>>` is locking the vector of vectors, but not the individual vectors
- Each individual `Vector<T>` inside it is locking the vector of `T` itself.

In other words, if you get two vectors of `T` from inside your vector of vectors, and give these vectors to different threads, you would be able to access the vectors simultaneously, without the threads locking out each other.

On the other hand, if you start accessing the vector of vectors concurrently, the accesses would be mutually exclusive, because the vector is synchronized.